# What is the best way to conditionally add key/value pairs to an object

Tags: javascript

I'm sending some data to my backend and I only want to add key/value pairs to my form data when they contain values.

Currently I'm conditionally added the values if they have a length greater than zero.

```
const personDetails = this.personDetails;
let formData = {}

if (personDetails.email.length) {
  formData.email = personDetails.email;
}
if (personDetails.phone.length) {
  formData.phone = personDetails.phone;
}

axios.put(url, formData).then(() => blah);
```

Is there a less verbose way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: you can iterate over the object and check it for each key and value pair instead of specifying them individually.

Comment: I use the formtojson.js code as included in the following post. Don't remember if I got it from a book or a website tute. I found an online reference by searching for one of the comments it contains. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509681/laravel-javascript-work-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lots of fields to do this with, you can use a loop so you don't have to repeat the `if` statements.

```
["email", "phone", ...].forEach(field => {
    if (personDetails[field].length) {
        formData[field] = personDetails[field];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the object all at once using the conditional operator instead:

```
const { email, phone } = this.personDetails;
const formData = {
  email: email.length ? email : undefined,
  phone: phone.length ? phone : undefined
};
```

This is not *strictly equivalent* to your original code because here, the properties will exist on the object regardless (but if the condition is not fulfilled, the associated value will be `undefined`). But since the result is being stringified when sent, this shouldn't be an issue.

If `formData` was being used *elsewhere*, and you explicitly iterate over properties, you'd have to make sure that the value associated with the property is not `undefined` first.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest *not* even using `if` statements to make conditional assignments:

```
formData.email = personDetails.email;
formData.phone = personDetails.phone;
```

Instead, just always assign an email and phone, even if they are null or empty.  The server side application receiving the input JSON would most likely be using a model which expects these fields to be present, even if unassigned.  The gain you would have by not even adding the email or phone key is fairly small.

Comment: In this case he can simply use `formData = {email: personDetails.email, phone: personDetails.phone};` instead of multiple assignments.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way as below to check if the length is equal or greater than you need.

```
var minLength = 6;    
for (var key in personDetails) {
    if (personDetails[key].length >= minLength) {
        formData[key] = personDetails[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on `personDetails` only having keys that need to be added to `formData`, and also depends on every value being an array

Comment: It's only an idea of how I solve this problem. It's the asker self to worry about the validation because no one knows better than him about the real structure.